# The calling thread cannot access this object even after adding Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety

The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it even after adding `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

The problem is still intact even after adding `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

```
async Task capturePredict()
{
    await Dispatcher.Invoke( async () =>
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder image = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        image.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

        using (Stream stream = File.Create(@"E:\ImageClassificationTraining\image.png"))
        {
            await Task.Run(() => image.Save(stream));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're using `Dispatcher.Invoke` but then turning around and calling `Task.Run` which gets you back in the thread pool, no longer on the dispatcher thread.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias this one `await Task.Run(() => image.Save(stream));`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i use the same way for another method and it work
`public async Task SendMsg()
        {
            await this.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
            {
                npesan = predictedLabel.Content.ToString();
                await Task.Run(() => RMQ.SendMessage(tujuan, npesan));
               
                predictedLabel.Content = "";
            });
        }`

Comment: You may have done the same with another method but in that case, what you were accessing from within the `Task.Run` wasn't a `DispatcherObject` derived type, like `PngBitmapEncoder` is.

Comment: Why are you calling `image.Save(stream)` from inside `Task.Run`? To keep the UI responsive?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes i want to keep the ui responsive

Comment: I just checked the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/windows/Media/Imaging/BitmapEncoder.cs.html#6886df05238e625c) of `BitmapEncoder.Save`. It starts by calling the [`VerifyAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.verifyaccess), which means that you can't call this method from any other thread than the UI thread.

Comment: @Theodor That's incorrect. You can't access a DispatcherObject from a thread other than the one it was created in. That is not necessarily the UI thread. However, creating the encoder inside the Task action won't help here, because it would itself still need access to the source bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to decoding a BitmapSource (which can be frozen to make it cross-thread accessible), encoding can seemingly not be done in a thread other than the UI thread.

You may however separate the encoding step from writing the file, by something like this:

```
public async Task SaveImageAsync(BitmapSource bitmap, string path)
{
    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
        {
            await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```